# Using http-request node and bearer authentication to connect to REST API

Tags: authorization, httprequest, node-red

For an application I need to connect to a REST API using Bearer authentication. The token is valid for 3 hours so I cannot fill it in statically in the http-request node itself.

I already tried to pass it as an object but every time the server returned a 401 code with the extra text that the token is not valid. When configuring the token inside of the http-request node, the server returns a 200 response with that same token.

I am testing it with an inject node which is connected to a function node which is connected to the http-request node. The function node contains the following code:

```
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer -mytoken-';

return msg;
```

Can somebody explain me why the token works when configured in the http-request node but not when passed as an object? Are there any settings that need to be done in the http-request node in order to accept the bearer token as an object?

Comment: I don't see how Node-RED wouldn't be setting this header, can you _guarentee_ that there isn't perhaps a bug with how you are generating the token? Or interpolating the string? I'm sure if you logged out the request you'd see the header is in there and being sent.

Comment: Hi, is there a way I can log this request with all its headers and contents so I can compare the 2 possibilities? The token itself is given by the server when you execute a get request. For now just to test i copy and paste the code Into the code given above. So I can’t see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you want to try this free, open source, HTTP capture software. It allows you to check the full URL, status, headers, and body of every request or response to examine exactly what's being sent. Link: https://httptoolkit.tech/view. It would be very kind of you if you could post here the results of your findings.

Comment: So after installing "HTTP Toolkit" I found the following: when activating the bearer authentication inside the http-request node, I could see the header authentication with the content "Bearer -mytoken-". When adding the authentication by using a function as described above, I only saw the content 'Bearer' but my token didn't show up. Maybe it is good to know that I am running node-red on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this workaround posted in Node-RED forum:

> Workaround: Go to the http request node, select Use authentication,
>   select basic authentication, leave username and password blank, select
>   Done to save. On returning the 'use authentication' will be
>   deselected. Authorization header should now be passed correctly when
>   set in the incoming message.

Credit: meesern

Comment: Even when setting the headers in the http request this solved my persisting "unauthorized" server response